# Please how do I fix "data.forEach is not a function" error shown up on my console

Tags: javascript

I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

My code:

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    data.forEach(function(user) {
      // do something with user
    });
  });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe4x8.png)

Comment: It looks like `data` is not an array, (probably an object?)

Comment: [How do I write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - tl;dr: write a title that summaries the problem and explain what the problem is, add a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem, don't post images of errors or code

Comment: @pilchard is correct, your API is responding with an object and not an array (https://reqres.in/api/users), object's do not have a `forEach` method

Comment: `data` is an Object with a `data` property. `data.data.forEach` should work

Comment: thanks a bunch @blex, i did used data.data.forEach() and it work perfectly well

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at your `data`, it's the following JSON:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "George",
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
    },
    // etc.
  ]
}
```

So (after having checked that `data` and `data.data` exist and that `data.data` is an array) you should iterate `data.data`, *e.g.*

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data && data.data && Array.isArray(data.data)) {
      data.data.forEach(function(user) {
        console.log(user);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the you should destructure **data** from the result like this

```
fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then({data} => data.forEach(user =>{ 
    //your code 
  }))
```